# Change size of radar/spider plot generated using ggradar package (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggradar

I have the following radar/spider chart generated using the `ggradar` package in R. I've tried to search how to adjust the size of the chart but I couldn't find any information, is there a way to do this? My issue is that when I want to embed the chart in a presentation, its practically not visible.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggradar)

data <- structure(list(Group = c("Dec 2019", "Dec 2020", "Dec 2021", 
"Jun 2022"), `Macroeconomic environment` = c(0.75, 0.85, 0.9, 
0.95), `Banking sector` = c(0.55, 0.52, 0.42, 0.39), `Corporate debt` = c(0.33, 
0.3, 0.35, 0.35), `Household debt` = c(0.45, 0.48, 0.48, 0.5), 
    `Non-banking financial sector` = c(0.5, 0.53, 0.58, 0.58), 
    `Payment and settlement systems` = c(0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2
    ), `Public Sector Debt` = c(0.77, 0.89, 0.95, 0.95)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data %>%
ggradar(group.colours = c('#6d1d26','#c7af76', 'grey', '#4B5320'),
          legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you already tried: `ggsave()`, with appropriate values for `height` and `width` normally picks reasonable font sizes for the desired plot dimensions.

Comment: When I run your code, it looks pretty big. Did you save your plot beforehand?